# Is there a way to conditionally highlight column cells based on dimension strings and metric values combined?

Tags: tableau-api

For example, I have an aggregated table that looks like this...

```
╔════════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ DCG            ║ Users   ║ UU      ║ Ratio ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ (Other)        ║ 74,000  ║ 5,000   ║ 6.75% ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ Direct         ║ 100,000 ║ 20,000  ║ 20%   ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ Display        ║ 45,000  ║ 100     ║ 0.22% ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ Email          ║ 150,000 ║ 60,000  ║ 40%   ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ Organic Search ║ 200,000 ║ 120,000 ║ 60%   ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ Social         ║ 90,000  ║ 18,000  ║ 20%   ║
╚════════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

What I want to do is keep all of those Ratio values as baseline benchmarks. When I break out the table by location like this for instance...

```
╔════════════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ DCG            ║ Users  ║ UU     ║ Ratio ║
╠════════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ (Other)        ║ 10,000 ║ 500    ║ 5%    ║
╠════════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Direct         ║ 15,000 ║ 2,000  ║ 13%   ║
╠════════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Display        ║ 8,000  ║ 6      ║ 0.07% ║
╠════════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Email          ║ 20,000 ║ 10,000 ║ 50%   ║
╠════════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Organic Search ║ 65,000 ║ 65,000 ║ 1.5%  ║
╠════════════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Social         ║ 10,000 ║ 4,000  ║ 40%   ║
╚════════════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

I want to have the Ratio values change colors to show the specific DCG values are either beating benchmark averages or are failing to meet the be benchmark average. In this case (Other) would be slightly red, Direct would be slightly red, Display would be a darker red, Email would be green, etc.

Is that possible? Would it also work if some DCG values are present in some locations but not others?

Something like this maybe but not this since it doesn't work...

`IF [DCG] = '(Other)' AND [Ratio] > 6.75% THEN 'Green' ELSE ' Red' ELSEIF [DCG] = 'Direct' and [Ratio] > 20% THEN 'Green' ELSE 'Red', etc.`

Comment: This can be done by FIXED LOD calculations because these work independently of filters.

Comment: If you can share your data (.twbx file) I may try to help you